# Set based solution for processing rows in a SQL table

Tags: sql-server

Can someone steer me in the right direction for solving this issue with a set-based solution versus cursor-based?

Given a table with the following rows:

```
Date        Value  
2013-11-01  12  
2013-11-12  15  
2013-11-21  13  
2013-12-01   0
```

I need a query that will give me a row for each date between 2013-11-1 and 2013-12-1, as follows:

```
2013-11-01   12  
2013-11-02   12  
2013-11-03   12  
...
2013-11-12   15  
2013-11-13   15  
2013-11-14   15  
...
2013-11-21   13  
2013-11-21   13  
...
2013-11-30   13  
2013-11-31   13
```

Any advice and/or direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that came to my mind was to fill in the missing dates by looking at the day of the year. You can do this by joining to the spt_values table in the master DB and adding the number to the first day of the year.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE(ADate Date, ANumber Int);
INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES
    ('2013-11-01',12),
    ('2013-11-12',15),
    ('2013-11-21',13),
    ('2013-12-01',0);

SELECT
    DateAdd(D, v.number, MinDate) Date
FROM (SELECT number FROM master.dbo.spt_values WHERE name IS NULL) v
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            Min(ADate) MinDate
            ,DateDiff(D, Min(ADate), Max(ADate)) DaysInSpan
            ,Year(Min(ADate)) StartYear
        FROM @Table
    ) dates ON v.number BETWEEN 0 AND DaysInSpan - 1
```

Next I would wrap that to make a derived table, and add a subquery to get the most recent number. Your end result may look something like:

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE(ADate Date, ANumber Int);
INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES
    ('2013-11-01',12),
    ('2013-11-12',15),
    ('2013-11-21',13),
    ('2013-12-01',0);

-- Uncomment the following line to see how it behaves when the date range spans a year end
--UPDATE @Table SET ADate = DateAdd(d, 45, ADate)

SELECT
    AllDates.Date
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 ANumber FROM @Table t WHERE t.ADate <= AllDates.Date ORDER BY ADate DESC)
FROM (
    SELECT
        DateAdd(D, v.number, MinDate) Date
    FROM
        (SELECT number FROM master.dbo.spt_values WHERE name IS NULL) v
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                Min(ADate) MinDate
                ,DateDiff(D, Min(ADate), Max(ADate)) DaysInSpan
                ,Year(Min(ADate)) StartYear
            FROM @Table
        ) dates ON v.number BETWEEN 0 AND DaysInSpan - 1
) AllDates
```

Comment: What happens when you look at a date range `15/12/2012` to `14/01/2013`?

Comment: That's an interesting point @ben. By rights, it should do a DateDiff on the Max and Min dates and add days from the Min. I'll look into updating my post.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, not sure how it compares to the two already posted performance wise but it's a bit more concise:

**Uses a numbers table:**

[Linky](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/)

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @SDATE DATETIME
DECLARE @EDATE DATETIME
DECLARE @DAYS INT

SET @SDATE = '2013-11-01'
SET @EDATE = '2013-11-29'

SET @DAYS = DATEDIFF(DAY,@SDATE, @EDATE)

SELECT Num, DATEADD(DAY,N.Num,@SDATE), SUB.[Value]

FROM Numbers N
LEFT JOIN MyTable M ON DATEADD(DAY,N.Num,@SDATE) = M.[Date]
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 [Value] 
             FROM MyTable M2 
             WHERE [Date] <= DATEADD(DAY,N.Num,@SDATE)
             ORDER BY [Date] DESC) SUB
WHERE N.Num <= @DAYS
```

--

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ac42/14/0)**

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but neither pretty nor very performant at scale:

In addition to `your_table`, you'll need to create a second table/view `dates` containing every date you'd ever like to appear in the output of this query.  For your example it would need to contain at least 2013-11-01 through 2013-12-01.

```
SELECT m.date, y.value
FROM your_table y
INNER JOIN ( 
        SELECT md.date, MAX(my.date) AS max_date
        FROM dates md 
        INNER JOIN your_table my ON md.date >= my.date
        GROUP BY md.date
    ) m
    ON y.date = m.max_date
```